# Rails 6 validate model only for specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got User model with validation:

```
validates :experience_level, inclusion: { in: EXPERIENCE_LEVEL, allow_blank: true }
```

But one of the part of full registration is to update User's experience level. User can do this by inside of below controller:

```
module Users
  class ExperienceLevelsController < SignupBaseController
    def edit
      authorize current_user
    end

    def update
      authorize current_user

      if current_user.update(user_experience_level_params)
        redirect_to new_appropriateness_test_step_one_path,
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end
  end
```

And for that endpoint I want to use

```
validates :experience_level, presence: true, inclusion: { in: EXPERIENCE_LEVEL }
```

I know I could use `on: :update` but in such case `User` will not be able to  update e.g. password if it doesn't go through the experience update form first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the model state aware you can do it by explicitly passing information into the model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :stage
  validates :experience_level, 
    inclusion: { in: EXPERIENCE_LEVEL }
  validates :experience_level, presence: true, if: :requires_experience_level?

  def requires_experience_level?
    stage == :add_experience_level
  end
end
```

```
module Users
  class ExperienceLevelsController < SignupBaseController
    def edit
      authorize current_user
    end

    def update
      authorize current_user

      if current_user.update(user_experience_level_params.merge(stage: :add_experience_level))
        redirect_to new_appropriateness_test_step_one_path,
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end
  end
end
```

There is also [`ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html):

> Abstract super class that provides a thread-isolated attributes
> singleton, which resets automatically before and after each request.
> This allows you to keep all the per-request attributes easily
> available to the whole system.

```
# app/models/current.rb
class Current < ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes
  attribute :stage
end
```

```
def update
  authorize current_user
  Current.stage = :add_experience_level
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attribute_accessor :stage
  validates :experience_level, 
    inclusion: { in: EXPERIENCE_LEVEL }
  validates :experience_level, presence: true, if: :requires_experience_level?

  def requires_experience_level?
    Current.stage == :add_experience_level
  end
end
```

Its really up to you if you want use it though as it [can be considered harmful](https://ryanbigg.com/2017/06/current-considered-harmful). If it quacks like a global...

Comment: Looking good, thanks! one question - when I'm trying to add `stage: :add_experience_level` directly to `user_experience_level_params` method which is `params.require(:user).permit(:experience_level)` to be params.require(:user).permit(:experience_level, stage: :add_experience_level) it does not include the `stage:` parameter. Does it have to be a merge instead? I thought it should work without merge

Comment: @mr_muscle if you want to pass it as a hidden input through the form you want `.permit(: experience_level, :stage)` - note that it will be string and not a symbol. Passing a hash to permit is used to whitelist nested keys. Not for assignment so if you want to set the parameter from controller then you want merge.

Comment: No, I don't wanna do anything with this. I will use it just as a fake hash param to recognize which validation I need to use inside of the model. From what I understand I have to use merge in such case.